# Visual studio "attach process" error: has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

Tags: c#

I have a dll for Tekla Structures (and source code in C#) that compiles perfectly (and also works), but I'm having problems with some new code (to extend the application) and I need to use debug to find the problem.  To `make debug` I need to use the "Attach process" of visual studio but when I use that option, it gives me the following problem:

> The program '[9132] TeklaStructures.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.".

Perhaps I don't know how to do it. Any solution/experience with this error?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say why the A/V happens, but you could go a different route and hard-code a `Debugger.Break();` statement in your DLL. That way, when you run the app normally, you should be prompted to attach a debugger when the break-point hits.

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering, sorry but I don't understand very well your solution? Can you explain me better? thanks

Comment: See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: OK. I found. Now is ok. Thank you!!